# Delphi decimal separator issue

Tags: delphi, format, decimal

My application works on system with regional settings where decimal separator is comma. (Delphi 10.1)

I have set dot as decimal separator for my application .

```
  Application.UpdateFormatSettings := false;
  FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator := '.';
  Application.UpdateFormatSettings := true;
```

This works fine for me.

I have used `format('%6.3f', 125.365])` function.
Exe is on for 24*7 on the system..

In the initial phase like 1 or 2 hours format function returns data properly with dot as decimal separator but later on it changes to local settings comma

say `12,365`.

How does dot changes to comma suddenly?

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation for UpdateFormatSettings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.UpdateFormatSettings)? *Specifies whether format settings are updated automatically when the user alters the system configuration.* I would leave it at *False*.

Comment: Do not rely on global settings of `FormatSettings`. Any part of your program could change the settings. Not thread-safe either. Use the overloaded versions of formatting floats where you pass your own `FormatSettings` record.

Comment: Alternatively, go with the flow and let your users see numbers in a form they expect.

Comment: @LURD: Thanks...I will do so..Is it happens only in Delphi higher versions?

Comment: Since Delphi-7 I think.

Comment: Delphi 7 still has `threadvar` global `DecimalSeparator`, `FormatSettings` was introduced in a later version

Comment: yes...i guess after delphi xe2

Comment: Delphi 2007 already has the FormatSettings parameter.

Answer (score 7):

Do not rely on the global `FormatSettings`. Use the second overload of `Format`, which allows you to specify your own `TFormatSettings`.

If you have a newer version of Delphi, you can directly use `TFormatSettings.Invariant`:

```
S := Format('%6.3f', [125.365], TFormatSettings.Invariant)
```

Or you create a new `TFormatSettings`:

```
S := Format('%6.3f', [125.365], TFormatSettings.Create('en-US'));
```

Or, e.g. in a version that does not have the `Invariant` or `Create` methods, you can set the values "by hand", of course. But set them in your own `FormatSettings`, not in the global one.

Answer (score 3):

get the local format setting and change it.

```
var
  fs:TFormatSettings;
begin
    fs:=TFormatSettings.Create(GetThreadLocale());
    GetLocaleFormatSettings(GetThreadLocale(),fs);
    fs.DecimalSeparator:='.';
end
```

Comment: No, "you must" not is not a good wording. Besides, your example makes no sense (you create new instance of thread locale settings, get default locale settings, modify them and nothing more). [no voting]

Comment: I used this and it worked (in delphi 10.3)- Previous versions did not need this

Comment: Your example makes no sense. You can insist, but it makes no sense. [I am not voting down here]

Comment: Why don't you test this in Delphi 10.3 ?

Comment: What is the OP supposed to do with that `fs` settings (I know, but I'm missing this in your answer)? Besides, I'd say [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44048567/960757) said the same in a proper way.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want people to mess with your stuff, use the kragle.
In this case it is an overload version of Format that accepts a FormatSettings record.

Create a unit like so:

```
unit DecimalPoint;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils;

var fs: TFormatSettings;

implementation
initialization
  fs:= FormatSettings;
  fs.ThousandSeparator:= ' ';  <<-- don't forget
  fs.DecimalSeparator:= '.'
end.
```

And add this unit to the `uses` where needed.

Now use it like so:

```
Str:= Format('%6.3f', 125.365],fs);
```

Comment: Stop gluing Lego pieces together! (although I know that in Legoland, they do that too <g>).

Comment: `const cMyFormatSettings : TFormatSettings = (DecimalSeparator : '.');` is even simpler. Gives #0 for the thousand separator, which is valid when no such character is wanted.